# verify my drbd configuration

Tags: centos, drbd

HI i try to add DRBD in centos7  with my two physical server, when i am try create  **drbdadm create-md drbd0**

error is **open(/dev/sdb3) failed: Device or resource busy** is it i am mapping correct drive in my configuration can someone verify and correct em
i added the both Fdisk screenshot and drbd res file

can anyone advice me or share any link ,it will great help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaENK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akqbZ.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste your plain text outputs and configurations as text and not images or "screenshots". I looked at your screenshots, and I don't see any mention of `/dev/sdb`, can you include output from `lsblk`?

Comment: @MattKereczman: [root@node2 ~]# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0  6.6T  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  1.5M  0 part
├─sda2            8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0  6.6T  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0 23.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0  6.5T  0 lvm  /home
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
[root@node2 ~]#

Comment: I would add things like that to your question, so it doesn't lose formatting like it does in the comments. Either way, I don't see `/dev/sdb` in any of that output, which is the block device you're trying to use as DRBD's backing device in the configuration.